# Blurry font rendering with smaller font sizes in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, chromium

VSCode uses *Electron/Chromium* for its GUI and inherits some font rendering problems from it. VSCode ships with default font Consolas 14px, but I consider Consolas 12px to be my standard, because it gives me much better overview of the whole code (on common 1920x1080 resolutions I consider font bigger than 12px to be a waste of space). However, **in this font size my code looks slightly fuzzy and with faded colors** (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TsDk.png)). It is so annoying when working with code, that it prevents me from using the VSCode editor. (Clear seeing of the code text is more important for me than all the VSCode IntelliSense features.)

This is definitively a **Chromium issue**, and I have also filed a bug on [Chromium bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1160271). The same issue happens with some webpages in Chrome and in every other Chromium-based IDE (e.g. *Atom*). Only old-school editors like *Notepad++* or *NetBeans* are OK.

I don't expect it to be repaired any time soon, and I have also tried whatever solutions possible (`--disable-gpu` flag, `workbench.fontAliasing` setting, `-webkit-font-smoothing` CSS property, trying different fonts...). It seems to be platform-independent (I've been testing on Windows + Linux and on different laptops).

So I can use smaller font which is blurry, or use bigger font which is impractical, or use another editor. I have chosen the last option. Anyway, **I am just trying to understand** why there are so many happy developers using VSCode, but just for me it is unusable. Is there something wrong with my eyes?

Comment: Obviously the blurry font rendering problem is caused by DirectWire font rendering which cannot be disabled in current Chromium browsers, see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1160271#c4